# Binary Insertion Sort as elements are being read into the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, binary, insertion-sort

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8893599

There is the code. This is the error message I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at Project2.insertInOrder(Project2.java:121) at Project2.main(Project2.java:49)

Meaning, the index is being set to 5 before the array length is doubled.

Comment: If you know what happens, why don't you fix it?

Comment: Please include the actual code, reduced down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, not an external link.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
else if (guess < key)
```

i think you are comparing an index with an element. Probably should be:

```
else if (a[guess] < key)
```

Comment: since guess is set equal a[mid] at line 135, it is indeed an element, same as key.

Comment: Why are you writing `int mid = lo + ((hi - lo)/2);`? You could use `(lo + hi)/2 ` .